# Looking for advice on how to get PyGame setup

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get PyGame working but am having a heck of a time getting it to run. The code is simple enough but for some reason I cannot get past importing PyGame. I use both python 2.7 and 3.5.1 and it's not working on either version.

I've tried the download 'executable' from the site and have also tried using the solutions that I've seen here with `brew install mercurial` and `brew install sdl` followed by the `brew install sdl sdl_ttf sdl_image sdl_mixer` command.

It's just not working and I hope there's a clean simple solution.
Thanks in advance!

```
MNickey$ python3 flappy.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flappy.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

Answer (score 0):

A.) Have you checked if you have a 32 bit or 64 bit version of pygame. Make sure it fits with your computer.

B.) Have you tried using pip install, I heard those work on pygame.

C.) Have you checked if the pygame versions themselves corresponds to your python version.

D.) Have you checked to see if the pygame module is even located in it's proper location, so in the python27 folder you should see a Lib folder which contains a site-packages folder where the module should be found.

They should work, and if not then I have obviously missed something. Judging from the error I think your pygame.base part of the module is missing. Best of luck in fixing this!